# Run shell builtin command in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, built-in

For training, I have idea to write a script which will display the last bash/zsh command.

First of all, I tried with `os.system` and `subprocess` to execute `history` command. But, as you know, `history` is a shell builtin, so, it doesn't return anything.

Then, I tried this piece of code:

`shell_command = 'bash -i -c "history -r; history"'
 event = Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,  stderr=STDOUT)`

But it have just shown commands from last session. What i want to see is the previous command (which i just typed)
I tried `cat ~/.bash_history` and have same result, unluckily.

Any idea ?

Comment: What did you expect/want it to show?

Comment: What happens if you put these commands in a shell script and run them?  Do you get the output that you want?

Comment: @EricRenouf  I's sorry if I made you confuse. but, i want it show the previous command, not commands in previous bash session

Comment: @dimo414 I tried it before, but it doesnt work, too :(

Comment: So your problem is that the contents of the history are not what you're expecting?  Bash does not write to .bash_history after every command, so you may just be getting the right results, but not quite what you want.  You could try running `history -a` before launching python to write that session to the file if that's what you want to see

Comment: Which tells us the problem is not with Python, but with Bash / your environment.  Start by getting it to work in Bash, and it should work in Python.

Comment: One of these questions ([one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/19157), [two](http://superuser.com/q/121195/16275), [three](http://superuser.com/q/37576/16275)) might address your issue.

Comment: @EricRenouf @dimo414 When I typed `history`, i received exactly what i want. The trouble is just happened when I tried to run it in Python

Comment: Right, you're in a different session when you're in python, so the shell `history` is not connected to the python view of bash's `history`.  That's why I suggested explicitly updating your history file if you want those results.  bash by default will keep a different history for each shell that's running, when you invoke it from within python you get a new view of the history that is not shared with the one that invoked it

Comment: @EricRenouf I have got what you mean. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tail` to get the last line:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

shell_command = 'bash -i -c "history -r; history"'
event = Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
           stderr=STDOUT)
out = Popen(["tail", "-n", "1"], stdin=event.stdout, stdout=PIPE)

output = out.communicate()
print(output[0])
```

Or just split the output and get the last line:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

shell_command = 'bash -i -c "history -r; history"'
event = Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
           stderr=STDOUT)
print(event.communicate()[0].splitlines()[-1])
```

Or read `bash_history`:

```
from os import path
out= check_output(["tail","-n","1",path.expanduser("~/.bash_history")])
print(out)
```

Or open the file in python and just iterate until you get to the end of the file:

```
from os import path
with open(path.expanduser("~/.bash_history")) as f:
    for line in f:
        pass
    last = line
    print(last)
```

Comment: I'm very sorry if i made you confuse, but, i just dont know how to get previous command, not commands from previous bash session.
anw, thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes. For example, after running `cat smtfile` command, i run my script and what it returns to me should contain `cat smtfile`

Comment: Ok, then that is a completely different story,  if it were for your own use you can add export `PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"` to your .bashrc file as described here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48113